# How to specify an "upload to" path in a Form File Field in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I'm not using a Model for this form, I know I can set the upload_to parameter inside a Model File Field, but seems not possible from the Form.

When I set the FileField the file is uploaded to the MEDIA_ROOT I setup on my settings. Although, I would like the file uploaded to /folder. Is it possible directly from the Form File Field or I must move the file manually?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to process the file manually from `request.FILES['formfieldname']` , this should provide a clear description for both cases (using the FileField in your model or manual handling from the request):
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/http/file-uploads/#basic-file-uploads

Comment: Yes, you're right. I see it is not even stored in a temporary folder. The file is kept in memory so you have to use a handle_uploaded_file function to move the file where you need it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to actually create your ImageField in Django models then inherit from the model into your form